# How to make alignment on the left side in the slick slider?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a slider. It shows three elements, but when there are two or one elements, then it centers them, and I need to be aligned to the left.

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.slider-blog').slick({
        arrows: false,
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,  
      });
 });
```

Comment: Please edit you question and include your relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: There was an indent ```margin-left: auto ``` , I did not notice, now I set 0 and off

Comment: I don't know why people are asking about exact html even when exact detail and question has been provided. Nobody has enough time to even ask a question.

Answer (score 12):

This works `.slick-track{ margin-left: 0; }`

Comment: how to use it dynamically? Like, I want to margin-left: 0 when a state is changed in my react app. Based on that condition, I want to change its properties.

Answer (score 4):

Just set your `margin` to `left 0` in `.slick-track`:

```
.slick-track {
    margin-left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
float:left;
```

inside class

```
.slick-track
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue but in Angular , you can try below solution

```
::ng-deep .slick-track{
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```